# How do I properly format HighStock x-axis ticks based on unix timestamps?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, highcharts, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having trouble properly labeling the x-axis ticks in my HighStock chart. Currently my chart looks like this:
[image]

The x-axis ticks are incorrect. The ticks should change dynamically based on the unixtimestamps within the data. An example of how it should look would be this:
[image]

How can I format the ticks based on dynamic unix timestamps?

For context, I'm using SignalR and a background task in an ASP.NET Core MVC application to periodically send [CoinGecko API](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation) data to the client, and displaying that data in a [HighStock chart](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/basic-line). My data is formatted as an array of arrays, `var dataArray = [ [unixTimeStamp, cryptoPrice],  [unixTimeStamp, cryptoPrice], ...]`. Click [here](https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=1&interval=minutely) if you would like to see the specific API data I am receiving.

HTML:

```
<div id="myChart" style="width:100%; height:500px;"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highstock/6.0.3/highstock.js" integrity="sha512-xStuxZIFeepdcpLwBhqIuU761mDfYUDbV8C8lUiTX96W+kyL+AYmY9l3o/Ku30gEek9l+hUJGQpmT4pcVm6LeA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script>
//Get data from Web API, I simplified this part for the question
var dataArray = [[insert unixtime, insert price], [[insert unixtime, insert price], ...]

//Get client time zone
var clientTimeZone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;

            //Initialize chart
            Highcharts.stockChart('myChart', {

                title: {
                    text: 'Bitcoin Price'
                },
                time: {
                    timezone: clientTimeZone
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Price',
                    data: dataArray,
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 2
                    },
                    showInNavigator: false,
                }],

                rangeSelector: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                xAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
</script>
```

Comment: What does it mean to format the scale based on the dynamic unix timestamp? Do you want to get the dynamic display scale every minute on unix?

Comment: @Chaodeng I will be requesting new data from the Web API every minute or so, and the data will contain new unix timestamps associated with every price. After working on the problem a little more, I think my issue is that I need to convert the unix time to the client's specific timezone somehow

Comment: @EthanPartridge - I reproduce your issue on the online editor - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hwobf932/ and I am not sure what kind of timestamp do you expect? How it should be calculated?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel I was wanting the timezone of the client to be taken into account and the unix timestamp dates adjusted accordingly, so that when a client is on this page, the graph dates and times are relative to where they live

Comment: @EthanPartridge have you tested `time.useUTC` property? https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.useUTC

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert the unix Epoch time. Below is sample method that may help. Ideally you will have the Zone id in the source, but I am not sure from where you are getting the data. If not use the Locale to find timezone info. Once you have converted the Unix Epoch date value you can use X axis Label format "g"

```js
public DateTime convertUnixEpochToLocalDateTime(long dateEpoch, string zoneId) {
  DateTime localDateTime;

  DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(dateEpoch);
  string timeZoneId = findTimeZoneId(zoneId);
  TimeZoneInfo currentTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);
  localDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime, currentTimeZone);

  return localDateTime;
}
```

You can do the opposite as below

```js
public long convertDateTimeToUnixEpoch(DateTime dtToConvert) {
  DateTimeOffset dtoffset = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(dtToConvert.Year, dtToConvert.Month, dtToConvert.Day, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc));

  return dtoffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
}
```